# Vote and Compare Blocks need to be taken out in magento

Tags: magento, sidebar

I have some troubles in /checkout/cart page with taking out two blocks:
- compare products block
- voting block

I cant remove them from right sidebar
at current layout xml

> ```
> /layout/checkout.xml
> ```

There is only MY ONE adding template to right sidedar

```
<reference name="right">
 my adding template code here
</reference>
```

also I have just removed all adding templates to right sidebar from

> /layout/page.xml

and as a result I see these two blocks (compare and voting) at right bar anyway (

Let me know where can They be removed by me from ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you're using `local.xml` to do your customizations.

In local.xml

```
<default>
<!--other codes-->
<remove name="catalog.compare.sidebar" />
<remove name="right.poll" />
<!--other codes-->
</default>
```

if need to remove from checkout - cart page only and retain on other pages then use `<checkout_cart_index>` handler instead of  and use `"unSetChild".` Remember `<remove>` will completely remove the block.

Comment: You can achieve almost anything with local.xml, which shows how powerful magento really is. It is the best and preferred way, so always avoid changing other XML files. Because, magento creates a temporary,global XML in each page render, thus overriding the functions as mentioned in local XML.

Answer (score 0):

I found out where was problem )

Magento layouts include one of this

> /layout/poll.xml

and There I saw these lines

> ```
>     <!-- Mage_Poll -->
>     <reference name="right">
>         <block type="poll/activePoll" name="right.poll">
>             <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/active.phtml</template><type>poll</type></action>
>             <action method="setPollTemplate"><template>poll/result.phtml</template><type>results</type></action>
>         </block>
>     </reference>
>
> </default>
> ```

after commented it  They disappeared )

Comment: Pascal, Yes this works, however Ans answer above is the proper way to accomplish this. If you were to upgrade Magento, these changes will be lost.